# Website Speed Test hitting 0/100 in "Page Speed Insight"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Website URL: http://gettycreations.com/

My Website is talking so much time to load because there are 300+ images on the home page. I checked it on "https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgettycreations.com%2F&tab=desktop".

I tried to put the code here but I got this "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 150616." error. Body does not allow put more than 30000 characters.

How may I solve that issue.

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to solve? How to put code here? How to load the website faster? Anyway are you really saying that in your home page you load all at the same time more than 300 images? I should advice you to rethink from scratch the page and think about loading the images only when needed. Users will not see all the 300 images all at the same time no?

Comment: You mean I should load minimum images when page load?

Comment: you should load just the images you need for start and go on loading on specific events: for example on page scroll, on button click or so on.

Comment: There is no use in loading 300 images on the homepage. As Lelio said try restructuring the site. Can you make categories out of those images? There is not just one solution for a slow website. There are many reasons to think of for a slow website (database performance, bandwith, server configuration, caching on the front or backend....)

Comment: @Learner what about loading just the first 9 images and then trigger a script that will load the following 9 when you scroll to see the second row of the first 9 (you can find plenty of examples about pagination on google)? Also consider using a preloading script to load the page before you show it: it is not good to see the background to appear secons later.

Comment: Generate some thumbnails for your images and load them when the page loads. Then when a user clicks on the image to expand it, load the full size image. Also, as Google has suggested, you should minify all of your code. For jQuery change `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js` to `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Thank you very much to give an idea........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load the images with JQuery once the page is loaded. An example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Load your images here
   $('.content').append("<img class='inline' src='/Images/img.png' />");
});
```

You can use a lot of tools to load content while you are scrolling down the page too.

Comment: Will you be so kind to share some code with us all elaborating your idea (that actually is the only feasible for this situation)

Comment: There is a little example. Suppose you have a <div class="content"></div>. Now you can dinamically append images to that div once the page was loaded.

Comment: It may fool Google but it's not an improvement (on the contrary). Compressing and lazy loading would be.

Comment: This code should just start loading the images on page ready. how should this be faster than what he has now? I agree with what @Shikkediel is saying. This is not pagination at all. If you want to have a look at something (I prefer to write my js when it is possible but this is a starting point) have a look at this [plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Comment: As I said, you can use a lot of tools to load the content while you are scrolling down the page. The code i wrote is just a tip to start loading images dinamically and then you can paginate it too.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I noticed looking at your code is that you load all pictures, including pictures that will be shown only when user click on magnifying glass. For instance you are loading 3d-22t.jpg (12.9 KB) image, which is a right size image but you also load 3d-22.jpg, which is 584 KB image and it's not used until you click on magnifying glass. What I would recommend is to load small images like you are doing now, but not load big images, and only load full size images when user clicks on subnail. Use ajax to load those images.

I also noticed that your images are not cached, so every time I open your page all images going from your web server instead of from local cache. You can use A [Last-Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.htmlhttp://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) and [Expires](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) header for that.

This will improve your page load speed drastically.

For more information read: [Image Optimization](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization#image-optimization-checklist), [How To Optimize Your Site With HTTP Caching](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/)